# How efficiently store and sort hashes for birthday attack

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

i have many (2^30 by 50 bits) outputs from hash function. i need to store it somehow and compare every new elem to all previous, and insert if its unique. If my array of hash values have not messed up while i inserted new elems, then i dont need to store hashed values, they are sequential.

How i can store it and then search for duplicity?

As values for hashing i use just "1","2","3","4",.....

EDITED:
BA on hash-function with output space 50 bits needs nearly 1.25*sqrt(2^50) tries. Every output 50 bit. So its nearly 250 Mbytes of space.

Comment: `std::set` or `std::map` appropriate here?

Comment: @BoBTFish, how it works with 250 Mb amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but perhaps you need to employ a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) as a preliminary check for existence of an element to speed up the process.

Please note, when the article says "m different hash functions", what it really means is, m different functions that can be the same algorithm with different parameters that produce unrelated results.  For example you can simply prepend the data to be hashed with a byte valued 0 through `m-1`.  Or you could take the 256 bits of a SHA256 hash and chop it up into groups of 24 bits or however big you need your filter to be.

Answer (score 0):

[Using](http://ideone.com/inJ3V) a [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

string toString(long value)
{
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << value;
    return oss.str();
}

long hash(const string& key)
{
    return 0;
}

string generateKey()
{
    static long value = 0;
    ++value;
    return toString(value);
}

pair<string, long> generateKeyValuePair()
{
    string key = generateKey();
    return make_pair(key, hash(key));
}
```

The main function:

```
int main()
{
    map<string, long> hashes;

    generate_n(inserter(hashes, hashes.begin()), 5, generateKeyValuePair);

    return 0;
}
```